# How to start disabled Launch Daemon?

Tags: macos, catalina, launchd

There are several launch daemons which I don't need running every day, but I want to run occasionally, for example Wireshark.  I disable it like this so it doesn't run at startup:

```
sudo launchctl disable system/org.wireshark.ChmodBPF
```

How can I manually run it while it's disabled?  It's not recognized by kickstart or print commands, even if I try enabling it first:

```
% sudo launchctl enable system/org.wireshark.ChmodBPF
% sudo launchctl kickstart system/org.wireshark.ChmodBPF
Could not find service "org.wireshark.ChmodBPF" in domain for system
```

The bootstrap command doesn't like this syntax even though this service-target works fine for disabling:

```
% sudo launchctl bootstrap system/org.wireshark.ChmodBPF 
Unrecognized target specifier. <service-target> takes a form of <domain-target>/<service-id>.
```

The only way I found that works is the legacy command:

```
sudo launchctl load -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.wireshark.ChmodBPF.plist
```

But this requires knowing the location of the plist.  Is there a modern way?